# Display errors of a form in different places without setting a variable for every input field

Tags: php

I hope you understand my title.

Instead of displaying a list of all the errors with the submitted form, I would like to show them beside the fields in the form:

This is a short snippet of my code:

```
$errors = array();

if (empty($subject)) {
    $errors[] = $lang['Empty Subject'];
}

if (empty($category)) {
    $errors[] = $lang['Empty Category'];
}

if (strlen($ath) > 255) {
    $errors[] = $lang['Too Long'];
}

if (!validate_string($str)) {
    $errors[] = $lang['Invalid String'];
}

and the list goes on...
```

And for displaying:

```
if (!empty($errors)) {
foreach ($errors as $error)
$page['errors'] = array();
    $page['errors'][] =  '<li class="red"><span>'.$error.'</span></li>';
}
```

I know I could set a variable for every error but that does not seem like a smart idea like, this would work but it seems so stupid:

```
if (empty($subject)) {
    $error_subject = $lang['Empty Subject'];
}

if (empty($category)) {
    $error_category = $lang['Empty Category'];
}
```

and then beside every field:

```
Subject:
<input type="text" name="subject"><?php echo isset($error_subject) ? '<span style="color: red">'.$error_subject.'</span>' : '';

Category:
<input type="text" name="category"><?php echo isset($error_category) ? '<span style="color: red">'.$error_category.'</span>' : '';
```

However that does only show 1 error at a time anyways.

How do pros do this?

Answer (score 0):

create the inputs dynamically

```
$inputs=array('subject','category');  //etc

foreach ($inputs as $input){
<input type="text" name="{$input}"><?php echo isset(${$error_.$input} ? '<span style="color: red">'.${$error_.$input}.'</span>' : '';
}
```